# A program to multiply real numbers (fractions) without the multiplication operator using loops

Tags: c++, loops, operators, multiplication

I was thinking that I may create a program to multiply numbers without using the (*) operator; however, the only problem is when it comes to numbers between zero and one or multiplying fractions together.

can anyone give me a hint please on how to edit my code to achieve this goal more efficiently? how can I use for loops with fractions for example?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std; 

int main()
{
    double num1, num2, m=0; int count=0; 
    cout<<"enter num1 then num2: "; 
    cin >> num1>> num2; 
    if (num1==0 ||num2==0) {m=0; cout<<m<<endl; return 0;  }

    if (num1>=num2)
    {while(count<num2)
{
    m +=num1; 
    count++; 
}
cout<<m; 
}
else if (num1<num2)
{
 for (double i=0; i<num1; i++)
    {
        m +=num2; 
    }
    cout<<m; 
}

  return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Don't compare `double`s inside for,while loops. It won't always do what you expect. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1286394/for-loop-in-c-using-double-breaking-out-one-step-early-boundary-value-not-rea . Comparing `double`s and `int` isn't good idea either.

Comment: I'm just guessing, but I guess that soon you'll want to read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this is an exercise and lets assume you have already a integer * integer multiplication working, then in a nutshell you can do the follwing:

Lets say you want N significant digits, then multiply each number by 10^(N/2) (you already know how to multiply with an integer), then truncate both numbers to integers, multiply the integers, divide the result by 10^N.

Answer (score 0):

If you want two multiply two fractions, you can multiply the nominators, denominators, then simplify the result by dividing the resulting elements by the gcd. The gcd can be calculated by Euclide algorithm. If you want to multiply two float numbers which are not available as fractions, you can first convert each of them to a close fraction. For a given precision 1/N, you can multiply each float by N, round it and get the numerator, N being the denominator.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <tuple>

//  Euclide algorithm
int gcd (int a, int b) {
    if (a < b) std::swap (a, b);
    while (b > 0) {
        int t = b;
        b = a % b;
        a = t;
    }
    return a;
}
    //  multiplication float * int
double mult_float_int (double a, int b) {
    double res = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < b; i++)
        res += a;
    return res;
}

//  double -> fraction
std::pair<int,int> float2frac (double x, int N) {
    int a = mult_float_int (x, N);
    int g = gcd (a, N);
    if (g == 0) g = 1;
    return std::make_pair (a/g, N/g);
}

//  multiplication a * b
int mult_int (int a, int b) {
    int res = 0;
    if (a < b) std::swap (a, b);
    for (int i = 0; i < b; i++)
        res += a;
    return res;
}

//  multiplication a0/b0 * a1/b1
std::pair<int,int> mult_frac (int a0, int b0, int a1, int b1) {
    int a2 = mult_int (a0, a1);
    int b2 = mult_int (b0, b1);
    int g = gcd (a2, b2);
    if (g == 0) g = 1;
    return std::make_pair (a2/g, b2/g);
}

int main()
{
    const int N = 100000; 
    int a0, b0, a1, b1, a2, b2; 
    double x, y;
    std::cout << "enter x : "; 
    std::cin >> x; 
    std::cout << "enter y : "; 
    std::cin >> y; 

    std::tie (a0, b0) = float2frac (x, N);
    std::tie (a1, b1) = float2frac (y, N);
    std::tie (a2, b2) = mult_frac (a0, b0, a1, b1);

    std::cout << x << " * " << y << " = " << a2 << "/" << b2 << "\n";
    std::cout << "Error = " << x*y - double(a2)/b2 << "\n";

  return 0; 
}
```

Demo:

```
    Process started (PID=7400) >>>
    enter x : 1.25
    enter y : 3.27
    1.25 * 3.27 = 327/80
    Error = 2.21177e-017
```

Note: the classical way to approximate a float with a fraction by multiplication by N was recalled by user463035818 first. A theoretical better way to approximate by a fraction is using continued fractions, see for example [Fractions instead of decimals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53267626/fractions-instead-of-decimals). However, doing it without multiplication or division is a challenge ...